# A word that means a box or a folder where one keeps one's personal items

Tags: word-choice

For example, a place where you keep your personal stories is a diary, what would one call a folder/box where you store personal items like: a love letter, a diploma or a small souvenir you got from a friend ...

The best word I could find is treasure, but it's not exactly that. Is there a word for this folder/box, or a better word than treasure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "[keepsake](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/keepsake)" or "memory" box. I have heard people refer to them as their "souvenir" or "treasure box" as well.